# Background of the image is bigger than the actual image

Tags: jquery, html, css

So basically, the backgrounds of my images are wighter than the actual image. And when I try to do something with them like enlarging or distorting them, the background of the image (not the actual image) goes out of the web page bounds. Here is an example, from `.smPicsContainer` .

[image]

As you can see the green line is the background of the BMW logo. My question is, is there a way to resize the background to match the actual image(the BMW logo).
Here is what I've dont so far:

```
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cars</title>
        <link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body class="body">
    <header class ="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img class="logoIMG" alt="Brand" src="images/brand.png">
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navMenu">
                        <ul class="menuItems">
                            <li><a href="#">Cunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Noob</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Butt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">GoBack</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- big pics-->
        <div class="picsContainer" id="cont">
            <ul class="pics">
                <li class="pic01" id="pic1"><img src="images\bmw3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="pic02" id="pic2"><img src="images\audi2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="pic03" id="pic3"><img src="images\porsche2.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- small pics-->
        <div class="smPicsContainer">
            <ul class="smPics">
                <li class="smPic1" id="pic4"><img src="images\BMWlogo2.png" alt=""></li>
                <li class="smPic2" id="pic5"><img src="images\audiLogo.png" alt=""></li>
                <li class="smPic3" id="pic6"><img src="images\porscheLogo.png" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery\jquery.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function() {

            $('#pic1').mouseenter(function() {
                $('#pic1').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic1').fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
                $('#pic4').animate({width: "40%", height: "40%"}, 'fast')
            });

            $('#pic1').mouseleave(function() {
                $('#pic1').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic1').fadeTo("fast", 1);
                $('#pic4').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic4').animate({width: "28%", height: "28%"}, 'fast')
            });

            $('#pic2').mouseenter(function() {
                $('#pic2').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic2').fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
                $('#pic5').animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'fast')
            });

            $('#pic2').mouseleave(function() {
                $('#pic2').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic2').fadeTo("fast", 1);
                $('#pic5').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic5').animate({width: "28%", height: "28%"}, 'fast')
            });

            $('#pic3').mouseenter(function() {
                $('#pic3').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic3').fadeTo("fast", 0.5);
                $('#pic6').animate({width: "50%", height: "50%"}, 'fast')
            });

            $('#pic3').mouseleave(function() {
                $('#pic3').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic3').fadeTo("fast", 1);
                $('#pic6').css("cursor", "pointer");
                $('#pic6').animate({width: "28%", height: "28%"}, 'fast')
            });
        });


    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body{

    background: linear-gradient(rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.7), rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.7)), url('../images/bgrIMG.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;    
}

header {

    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
}

#bg {

    background:url('../images/bgrIMG.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    height: 500px;
}
.navbar {
    width: auto;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #858585;
}

.container-fluid {

  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;

}

.navbar-header {
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
}

.navbar-brand {

  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand .logoIMG {

    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.6%;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
}

.logoIMG:hover {

    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform:scale(1.25);
}
.navMenu {

    float: right;
}

.navMenu .menuItems {

    font-family: BebasBold;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 48px;
}

.menuItems a {

    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0  20px;

}

.menuItems li {

    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 20px;
    transition: background 0.2s;

}

.menuItems li:hover {

    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    border-bottom: solid #321DF2;
}

.menuItems a:hover {

    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #999;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 5%;
}

.content .picsContainer {
    height: 20%;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
}

.content #cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

}

.content #cont .pics{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content #cont .pic01 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content #cont .pic02 {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 33.3%;
    left: 33.3%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content #cont .pic03 {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 33.3%;
    left:66.6%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content .picsContainer img {

    width: 100%;
}

.content .smPicsContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 4.5%;

}


.content .smPicsContainer .smPic1 {

    background-size: cover;
    wight: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;

}

.content .smPic2 {

    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 35%;
    list-style-type: none;

}

.content .smPic3 {

    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    left: 70%;

}

.content .smPicsContainer img{

    width: 15%;
}

@font-face {

    font-family: 'BebasBold';
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("../fonts/BebasNeue Bold.otf");

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px){

    .navbar {

    min-height: 230px;

}

    .navbar-brand img {

    display: none;
}

    .navMenu .menuItems {

    height: 172px;
}


    .menuItems li {
        width: 100%;
        top: 0.1%;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        float: right;
    }

.content #cont .pic {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

}
```

I'll provide more information if needed. Keep in mind I'm pretty new to web developing. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You need to post the CSS for `<header class ="navbar">` element and its children, since most likely it is there you have that green background

Comment: Done. I edited the post.

Comment: you have an extra `"` here

   `<link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"" />`

should be like this:

   `<link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: The posted image and html/css rendered result doesn't match, so no way to understand and be able to suggest any solution.

Comment: Oh, yes. Didn't notice it. I know it's really messy, but I just started learning it. Thanks for the correction. But it still works the same.

Comment: It matter to us what to look for, so my only now advice is, look for the element which is green and make it transparent.

Comment: Don't know what might cause the problem. It is the same css/html code I'm using at the moment, and it renders just fine.

Comment: Yes, I purposedly made the background green, so I can show you more clearly what is the problem. I just want to resize that green background so it can match the logo image.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - if you want to give your container a style, position that absolutely rather than the image inside of it.

```
.navbar-brand {
display:inline-block;
}
```

This will resize the container to the size of the content.

Comment: The image that I posted is not from the navbar. It is from the .smPicsContainer, where I put all the logo pics.